# UICollectionView doesn't align cells properly (big gaps between them)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a `UICollectionView` that displays two kind of cells according to whether the item in its datasource is a "folder" or a "photo"

It appears that when the `UICollectionView` is populated with both type of cells and when there are less than 3 number of "photo" cells to show per row, the cells are not being left-aligned one next to each other but rather try to fill out the whole empty space of the row.

**Preview 1:**

[image]

**Preview 2**

[image]

However when the exact `UITableViewCollection` displays only "photos" cells, it seems to be behaving normally:

[image]

Here are the delegate methods that handle the cell sizes and spacing:

```
extension DropboxBrowserViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
{

    let folderTypeCellHeight = CGFloat(64.0)
    let collectionViewWidth = collectionView.bounds.size.width
    let numOfPhotosPerRow = CGFloat(3.0)
    let layout = collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    let insets = (layout.sectionInset.left, layout.sectionInset.right)

    // Go full width if the cell displayed a folder name
    if let _ = listingsDataSource?.listings[indexPath.row] as? Files.FolderMetadata {
        return CGSize(width: collectionViewWidth, height: folderTypeCellHeight)
    }
    // return size to fit `numOfPhotos` photos per row
    else {

        let cellSpacing = SavePhotosCollectionViewCell.cellSpacing

        let cellSize = (collectionViewWidth - insets.0 - insets.1 - (CGFloat((numOfPhotosPerRow - 1)) * cellSpacing)) / numOfPhotosPerRow
        return CGSize(width: cellSize, height: cellSize)

    }

}

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat
{
    return 2.0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0.0
}
```

Any ideas on why this might be happening?

Thanks

**EDIT**

The storyboard looks like this. I don't why the "photos" cell is being displayed in the middle over there and if this has something to do with the issue.

[image]

Comment: I have this problem now. Could you solve it?